# FtpWebRequest - Erro arquivos grandes

Tags: c#, upload, ftp

Tenho uma aplicação desktop feita em c# rodando alguns meses em um cliente.
O mesmo solicitou um módulo para realizar uploads e downloads em um servidor FTP, o banco de dados atualmente está nas nuvens pelo KingHost, como esta empresa já oferece o serviço, optei por continuar nela, porem estou com alguns problemas...

Meu algoritmo não apresenta nenhum problema para realizar upload em arquivos pequenos, porem arquivos com mais de 20MB está ocorrendo o seguinte erro:
"A conexão subjacente estava fechada: Erro inesperado em um recebimento"

Entrei em contato com a empresa de hospedagem e fui informado que nenhum problema foi localizado.

DETALHE: depois de alguns minutos do erro, ao verificar o ftp o arquivo está lá...

Segue algoritmo:

```
                    FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(cboServidor.Text + cboGrupoArquivo.Text + "/" + Path.GetFileName(openFileDialog1.FileName));
                    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
                    request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(txtUsuario.Text, txtSenha.Text);
                    request.UsePassive = true;
                    request.UseBinary = true;
                    request.KeepAlive = false;


                    FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(openFileDialog1.FileName);
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[stream.Length];

                    stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    stream.Close();

                    Stream reqStream = request.GetRequestStream();
                    reqStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    reqStream.Close();
```

Comment: Teste em outro FTP para ver se o problema persiste. No pior dos casos, tente enviar o arquivo em pedaços, fazendo APPEND em vez de mandar de uma vez (não é o ideal, mas se tiver que continuar na mesma hospedagem, e não conseguir resolver o timeout ou erro). De qualquer forma, o ideal mesmo é localizar o problema. Tente com buffers de tamanhos diferentes para ver se muda o comportamento. Comece um de uns 4k, depois vá aumentando. Tente também alternar o `request.KeepAlive`, pode ser que o FTP da tal hospedagem precise desses contornos.

Comment: eu coloquei tempo pra timeout e mudei o KeepAlive para true...
demorou mas foi, voce sabe dizer oq pode ter influenciado?

Comment: o keep alive fica trocando uns pacotes de tempos em tempos pra nao derrubar a conexão, pode ser uma das causas. Mas ao certo, não dá pra dizer sem testes